# Where should I place CustomControllerFactory class in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture

I have seen some tutorials putting this class in the **model** folder, but this is not a model nor a controller or view. Where should I place `CustomControllerFactory` class in Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: It is just a personal preference. Normally, I place  reusable components inside a separate Class Library. If it is just a single file, you can just create a folder called `Infrastructure` inside MVC application, and place it there.